# Precompiled handlebars template doubles the file size

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars templating engine on my app, which mainly aims at **desktop browsers**.

Currently I distribute all my templates in HTML and compile them in the browser. I want to apply precompiling to my templates to make my app faster, but things didn't work as I thought.

I run commands like this to precompile and minimize my templates:

`handlebars -m example.handlebars -f example.js`

Then I've got the `example.js` with **the file size doubled**!

I do cut down the consume of browsers without compiling templates and the runtime package of handlebars is much smaller. But the file size of my templates costs me more than what I've got.

So did I make anything wrong when precompiling my templates?
Or did I misunderstand the meaning of precompiling templates?

Answer (score 2):

There will always be an overhead in size when precompiling templates, since expressions like this:

```
<div>{{values.abc}}</div>
```

Will be compiled to something like:

```
function program(data) {
  return '<div>' + program2(data) + '</div>';
}
function program2(data) {
  return data.values ? data.values.abc ? data.values.abc : '' : '';
}
```

But here size shouldn't be a major concern. If it is you should consider dynamically loading the templates when they are required, instead of sending everything to the client at once.

Comment: To cut back "some" (albeit very little) size, I minify my handlebars HTML before pre-compiling.
However, don't fret over increased file size because of precompilation - it is a MAJOR improvement over client-side compilation.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel HTML minifying usually doesn't give much since everything will be send gzipped anyway. While JavaScript minifying (uglifying) can help a little extra since the structure of the code can be changed as well as spaces, newlines can be removed.

Comment: But dynamically loading the templates can not solve the "expanded file size" problem. A larger file takes more time in network transferring, so I doubt if it is worth doing so. I tested the templates compiling speed in chrome and it was extremely fast.

Comment: @AmBeta And so is downloading a few more kilobytes.